# PDF on GitHub repository front page?

Tags: html, pdf, github, markdown

Is it possible to have the front page of a GitHub reopsitory display a PDF document instead of the README.md file? So that the repository looks like this (photoshopped image):

[image]

Compared to this, which is how it actually looks with the README.md:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pushing a file called `README.pdf`?

Comment: Yes I tried, it didn't recognize the file.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Comment: Only solution I found is to convert pdf to image and display images. There are tools for converting, like https://pdf2png.com/ .

Comment: ...converting a PDF to an image and using it as your README is a _terrible_ idea. it destroys accessibility. The officially-supported formats (Markdown, Org, ReST, plain text, etc.) are by far the best choices.